# Black Lines Along UV Mapped Model

Tags: texturing, uv

I am new to blender and am trying to model an object and export it to unity.

However I am having a problem. Black line are forming along several edges of the model when viewed from a distance.

Some screenshots

Close Up
[image]

From A Distance
[image]

In Unity
[image]

Texture
[image]

Comment: It might help to post the texture with the UV islands overlaid to see how it's unwrapped.

Comment: Looks like you need a larger margin around the outside of the UVs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either remap your UVs with `smart UV project` and set `island margin` to an appropriate value (Experiment, 0.02 works for me), or manually increase the size of the margin around each island by a few pixels. You can easily do this by hand with a photo-editing tool.

The black lines are from the mipmapping used in realtime graphics pipelines, including Blender's editor and Unity. The mipmapping works fine at full resolution (eg: when close to the model) but when the camera is far away, adjacent colours tend to blend together. On your texture, coloured islands are adjacent to black areas, so you have black lines.

[This Gamedev.SE](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/50037/66352) answer is wonderful and explains the mipmap bleed effect very well.

Comment: Source: My own problems with mipmapping and colour bleeding (unrelated to Blender) and my fix translated to Blender terms, as well as the wonderful link at the end of my answer. You can search for information regarding "Mipmap texture bleeding" if you want more of the gory details from various people on the 'net.