# Problem with 3d models imported from Blender to Unity - the seams are visible as black lines when zooming

Tags: materials, uv, edges, texture-painting, unity

I created a couple of characters using Blender for my game in Unity. Everything, that is imported from Blender to Unity - there are visible black lines on the places, where there are "seams" in Blender. When I zoom in, close to the character - the black lines disappear. This problem is not only in Play mode but even in Edition mode in Unity.
How Can I fix this? Maybe I have to make any additional settings in Blender when I make seams, or when I paint the character?
I attach 2 pictures - when is zoomed out, and when it is zoomed in. What can I do?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Finally I found the answer, here is another post in the forum: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32711/black-lines-along-uv-mapped-model

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, you have not defined a padding/margin to the edge in Texture Paint.

If you draw it without margin, your painting will end exactly at the edges:

[image]

In Unity it will look like this (depending on antialiasing and distance to the object):

[image]

To avoid the problem, you would have to set the `Bleed` option in *Texture Paint* under `Tools` > `Options` to a higher value. Preferably to *2px* or *4px*:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I did these instructions, I made the Bleed to be 4 px (before it was 2px). Unfortunately, there was no result. In UNITY, in Project settings, I also tried all 3 options of antialiasing, but again it was without result. The black lines are again visible when it is zoomed out. Any other idea what can I do?

Comment: @sirtak Did you repeat the texture paint with a higher bleed value, and also resave the texture and import it into Unity? ...please check this again, or share your blend-file.

Comment: I admit - I did not make it :). I only changed the bleed to 4 px and imported it again in Unity, but I did not repaint everything. Now, with this instruction, I will do it, and I will write what is the result. Thanks :)

Comment: btw: If you still don't get the result you want, it could be that you accidentally moved your UV mapping.

Comment: I performed these instructions, and now the things are a little bit better - the black lines are thinner. Now, although it is more difficult, they are again visible. What do you mean UV mapping is moved?
When I changed the picture for painting, first again I made UNWARP, and after that started to paint. Thanks for the instructions, but do you have any other idea, about how can I make things better?

Comment: @sirtak Please share your file, it's hard to find an exact answer here.

Comment: Search for "mipmap" settings in Unity.

Comment: Hello, I still can't find an answer to this question, I left it for a long time, because I had another thing to do for my project, but now this issue is again actual. Can anybody help me, I share the file with the character: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Q5iWXWwH_CywyRDQ-kpcc7evM3fnHtjV/view?usp=sharing